# Notepad++ 7.7.1 Color Syntax Higlighting with NPPExport is not working

Tags: notepad++

I tried copying android source code with syntax highlighting from Notepad++ using NppExport Plugin (Copy RTF to Clipboard) to Word (with Keep source formatting) while pasting, but unfortunately it copies only with the syntax formatting, and doesn't retain the color. Please help.

Comment: I also tried replacing with the latest NPPExportdll 0.2.9.21. The color formatting is still not retained while copying from notepad++ and pasting in word/notepad++

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, just download the latest version of Notepad++.